# How to update a Google's URL to a portion of my site?

Tags: domain-name-system, wordpress, seo

I have wordpress server contoso.com/blog. I want to retire the server so I created blog.contoso.com and set dns redirects to point all contoso.com/blog to blog.contoso.com.

Now when I Google "contoso+blog," it still shows contoso.com/blog, not blog.contoso.com.

Any ideas on how to fix the issue? I'm about to edit the htaccess file to hopefully redirect traffic, but I want to retire the old server and don't want to pay AWS just for redirecting any traffic from old server to be server.

Comment: There is no such thing as DNS redirect, can you clarify what exactly it is?

Comment: Generally SEO questions are more on-topic on Webmasters SE.  - Naive question: When you have a server running the blog.contoso.com website, why don't you use name based virtual hosting to also host a second  minimal website there for `[www.]contoso.com` that continues to redirect contoso.com/blog  and displays  "nothing to see here"  or something similarly terse for all other requests...

Comment: Editing the . htaccess file to point to blog.contoso.com or updating route 53 alias records. Rote53 had been updated, but navigating to contoso.blog.com/blog/page1 will not redirect to blog.contoso.com.